# For each loop in php

Tags: php, foreach

So, I've been experimenting with `foreach` loops in PHP as a way of reading and displaying the contents of a CSV file. This is what I have so far:

```
$file = file("games.csv");
foreach($file as $k)
    $csv = explode(',',$k);
    echo "<tr> 
        <td>$csv[0]</td>
        <td>$csv[1]</td>
        <td>$csv[2]</td>
        <td>$csv[3]</td>
        <td>$csv[4]</td>
        </tr>";
?>
```

It works but only displays the last record in the CSV file. Why is this? Until I can understand why, I don't think I can fix the issue and display all records.

Comment: foreach body is missing

Comment: Thank you so much for all your replies. This has definitely helped me understand the purpose of curly braces! Thank god for stack overflow and all the good people on it to support amateurs like me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add curly braces `{` `}` around the body of your `foreach`. The syntax you're using means only the first line gets looped.

```
foreach($file as $k) {
    $csv = explode(',',$k);
    echo "<tr> 
        <td>$csv[0]</td>
        <td>$csv[1]</td>
        <td>$csv[2]</td>
        <td>$csv[3]</td>
        <td>$csv[4]</td>
        </tr>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to do like this, In your current syntax it will consider on first line as the part of foreach body, this is the reason it is echoing only last line of you CSV file.

```
<?php
    $file = file("games.csv");
    foreach($file as $k)
    {
        $csv = explode(',',$k);
        echo "<tr> 
           <td>$csv[0]</td>
           <td>$csv[1]</td>
           <td>$csv[2]</td>
           <td>$csv[3]</td>
           <td>$csv[4]</td>
       </tr>";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is why all control blocks (ifs and loops) should be wrapped in braces... Your code is only looping the first statement immediately following the foreach.

```
$file = file("games.csv");
            foreach($file as $k) {
                $csv = explode(',',$k);
                echo "<tr> 
                        <td>$csv[0]</td>
                        <td>$csv[1]</td>
                        <td>$csv[2]</td>
                        <td>$csv[3]</td>
                        <td>$csv[4]</td>
                    </tr>";
            }

        ?>
```